# Facing "error calling ge: incompatible types for comparison" in helm template

Tags: go, kubernetes-helm, helm3

I'm trying to set pdb value based on hpa min replica value using below logic

```
spec:
{{ if (ge .Values.autoscaling.minReplicas 5) }}
  minAvailable: 80
{{ else if (eq .Values.autoscaling.minReplicas 4) }}
  minAvailable: 75
{{ else if (eq .Values.autoscaling.minReplicas 3) }}
  minAvailable: 65
{{ else if (eq .Values.autoscaling.minReplicas 2) }}
  minAvailable: 50
{{ else }}
  minAvailable: 0
```

But I'm facing this error when I perform dry run

```
Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: template: service/templates/pdb.yaml:11:7: executing "service/templates/pdb.yaml" at <ge .Values.autoscaling.minReplicas 5>: error calling ge: incompatible types for comparison
helm.go:84: [debug] template: service/templates/pdb.yaml:11:7: executing "ffservice/templates/pdb.yaml" at <ge .Values.autoscaling.minReplicas 5>: error calling ge: incompatible types for comparison
INSTALLATION FAILED
main.newInstallCmd.func2
    helm.sh/helm/v3/cmd/helm/install.go:127
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute
    github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.4.0/command.go:856
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC
    github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.4.0/command.go:974
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute
    github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.4.0/command.go:902
main.main
    helm.sh/helm/v3/cmd/helm/helm.go:83
runtime.main
    runtime/proc.go:255
runtime.goexit
    runtime/asm_amd64.s:158
```

I tried enclosing .Values.autoscaling.minReplicas with int like this,
{{ if (ge int(.Values.autoscaling.minReplicas) 5) }} but still facing same error

Can someone please help me with this error, how do I define the value as int and perform comparison?

Answer (score 6):

Sorry, I found the answer

I should have compared like this

```
spec:
{{ if (ge (int .Values.autoscaling.minReplicas) 5) }}
  minAvailable: 80%
{{ else if (eq (int .Values.autoscaling.minReplicas) 4) }}
  minAvailable: 75%
{{ else if (eq (int .Values.autoscaling.minReplicas) 3) }}
  minAvailable: 65%
{{ else if (eq (int .Values.autoscaling.minReplicas) 2) }}
  minAvailable: 50%
{{ else }}
  minAvailable: 0%
```

Hope it helps anyone, if they do this same silly mistake

Comment: `{{- if (eq (int .Values.replicaCount) 1) }}` worked for me! thanks!

Comment: Are all values considered as string?

Comment: @SimonLogic Actually, anything numeric that comes from `values.yaml` (or any similar source) is treated as a float, whereas the templates distinguish between float and int. This is because, even though YAML fully supports a distinction between float and int literals, as part of processing the `values.yaml` data is round-tripped through JSON, and JSON only has floats. It then hides this by lopping off the trailing zero when rendering as a string.

Comment: sorry, i don't undertand how your comment is applicable to the poblem above. from my point of view ge, eq etc consider values from values.yaml strictry as string, and threrefore require explicit type conversion.